# preg_match form field validation error if "&" in string

Tags: php, validation, preg-match

I am trying to validate a form field.

```
if (empty($_POST["title"])) {
    $titleErr = "A title is required";
} else {
    $title = test_input($_POST["title"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 &'-]*$/",$title)) {
        $titleErr = "Only letters numbers spaces &'- allowed";
    }
}
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
```

I get an error if there is an "&" in $title. I have tried using "\&" and changing the order but to no avail.

Comment: "test_input" doesn't "test" anything, it's a nonsense function propagated by W3Schools. Stop using it.

Comment: Provide a sample input and desired output, please.  What are you "putting in" that is causing the error that is undesirable? And what should it do?

Comment: "test_input" replace the `&` by `&amp;` and since the `;` isn't valid for your pattern, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086665/preg-match-form-field-validation-error-if-in-string#comment85178894_49086665), [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) will replace `&` with `&amp;`, its html representation. In turn, the semicolon character makes the `/^[a-zA-Z0-9 &'-]*$/` regex fail.

It's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve, but if you are trying to insert the value in a database with sql, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and parameterized queries to protect against sql injection, not half-baked sanitization functions that ultimately do not protect against sql injection.

In any case, you could just remove that test_input function, it neither serves nor achieves any purpose.